# Using a drop down list to populate values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Column A I have a dropdown list of numbers ranging from 0-10. This is the census. In Column B I would like it to populate with the number of staff I need based on the corresponding number on the dropdown in Column A. (Refer to below). So I have the dropdown of "Census" in Column A. I would like Column B "Staff Needed" to populate with whatever number I select in the dropdown under "Census". For example, If I select 2 under "Census" then 1 should appear under Staff. If I select 6 under Census then 3 should appear under Staff. I've tried using Data Validation but seem to not quite get it. NOTE: I do not want a 2nd dropdown list. I simply want Column B to autopopulate based on what I select from the dropdown in Column A. Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you.

```
Census
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9 
10

Staff Needed 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MATCH:

```
=MATCH(A1,{0,1,3,5,7,9})-1
```

OR

```
=ROUNDUP(A1/2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner’s answer(s) will work
as long as your correspondence array is 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5,
but he doesn’t explain how to adapt his answer(s)
if the details of your problem change.

```
=INDEX({0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5}, A1+1)
```

uses your data in an obvious way, and so is easily adaptable.

On the other hand, Scott Craner’s answer(s) work
for values of `A1` greater than 10, and this one produces an error.